# explanation on recursion function in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am a beginner in python and am not getting the concept of recursion.can i get an explanation of the code below:

```
def rec(k):
    if(k>0):
        print('the value of k is:',k)
        result = k+rec(k-1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result
rec(8)
```

the output is:

```
the value of k is: 8
the value of k is: 7
the value of k is: 6
the value of k is: 5
the value of k is: 4
the value of k is: 3
the value of k is: 2
the value of k is: 1
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
```

How is it that we are not getting `print(result)` after each `print('the value of k is',k)`

Comment: You *are* getting the result printed afterwards, on the way back *out* of the stack of recursive calls.

Comment: Why would `print(result)` be the next thing that is being executed? Python is busy executing `rec(k-1)` *first*, and that function call also prints, etc.

Comment: Imagine a line of people that you give instructions: Accept a number, *shout* that number, then give the number minus 1 to the next person. When that next person hands you back their result, add that result to your number, shout the result of the addition, and then hand back the result to whomever had given you the first number. Do you think everyone will shout twice directly, or will they wait?

Comment: Put differently, why would Python already know what to print as `result` when the `rec(k - 1)` call hasn't completed yet? How would a person in your line of people know what to shout for the result without waiting for the next person to be done first, and why would they wait with shouting the first number when given?